# How to migrate zoho mail to google workspace 2023

Tags: email, migration, zoho, google-email-migration

Although it can be a little complex, switching from Zoho email to Google Workspace is definitely possible. The general procedures are as follows:

https://techpostal.blogspot.com/2023/05/move-your-zoho-mail-account-to-google.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the steps on how to migrate the emails from your Zoho Mail account to Google Workspace.

The answer to that question is going to be in this article. [Migrate email with the data migration service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9476255). This contains the steps on how to start the Data Migration Service of Google Workspace and also gives IMAP servers of other service providers under

> Connection information for common IMAP-based webmail providers